# Can msbuild.exe be set to compile a set number to source files before generating code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, msbuild

When building a large project msbuild appears to break the larger projects into 20 source file compile units. Compile 20 *.ccp and then Generated Code. On Win7 64 bit all works very well. However, on windows 7 32 bit  and XP 32 bit the compiler frequently will crash due to heap exhaustion or just running out of space. This seems to be random. I want to set the compile chunks to less than 20 and see if performance improves.

Can msbuild.exe be set to compile a set number to source files before generating code?

Comment: How are you using MSBuild? Are you simply calling MSBuild with the solution file?